# Comparison between Servlet Context and Third party Cache(like ehcache)

Tags: jakarta-ee, ehcache

In my web application I have many static list. These static list are generated by querying from database. Now I'm generating this list during start up of my application server and store them in the Application Context. I can do the same using a third party object cache framework like ehcache. Now the question is which one is the better approach. Is there any limitation if I use the Application Context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know this dataset is static and fits in memory, the you are fine with your `ApplicationContext`.

What a caching solution would do is give your more flexibility around eviction - based on limits you would set yourself - and expiry - based on how fresh the cached data must be - of cached elements.

Comment: is right in the context servlet listener define a static list, and a static get of the list, and access it via servletcontextlistener.getlist() ??